# Optionnal parameter in SEARCH CFQL method not of type varchar

Tags: codefluent

Is it possible to have a search function that would allow passing optional parameters other than varchar (i.e. DateTime, decimal .. ) ?

I need to search rows that are in a date range. User should be able to search FROM a date only, or up TO a date, or even in a FROM-TO range.

My approach was to create a SEARCH method with Date parameters. Those are correctly converted to DateTime object in CFE, but I won't be able to pass null value.

I managed to create a SEARCH method with unchecked parts, but those parts won't get optionnal in the body of the function.

How can I get fromDate and toDate parameters to be set as optional ?

CFQL body is

```
SEARCH(string amount, string fromDate, string toDate, string otherEntityId, date date) WHERE [$Entity::Date$ >= CAST(@fromDate AS DATE)] AND [$Entity::Date$ <= CAST(@toDate AS DATE)] AND OtherEntity.OtherEntityId = @otherEntityId AND Amount = @amount and date = @date
```

Body procedure generated is as follow. Notice the unchecked parts that aren't optionals

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[Entity_NameOfProcedure]
(
 @amount [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @fromDate [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @toDate [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @OtherEntityId [nvarchar] (256) = NULL,
 @date [date] = NULL,
 @_orderBy0 [nvarchar] (64) = NULL,
 @_orderByDirection0 [bit] = 0
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @paramlist nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql=
'SELECT DISTINCT * /*on purpose for stackoverflow */
    FROM [Schema].[Entity]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Schema].[OtherEntity] ON ([Schema].[Entity].[Entity_OtherEntity_OtherEntityId] = [Schema].[OtherEntity].[OtherEntity_OtherEntityId]) 
    WHERE (([Entity].[Entity_Date] >= CAST(@fromDate AS DATE) AND ([Entity].[Entity_Date] <= CAST(@toDate AS DATE) AND ((1 = 1) AND ((1 = 1) AND (([Schema].[OtherEntity].[OtherEntity_NumberInt] LIKE ''6%'') AND (1 = 1)))))) AND (1 = 1))'
SELECT @paramlist = '@amount nvarchar (256), 
    @fromDate nvarchar (256), 
    @toDate nvarchar (256), 
    @otherEntityId nvarchar (256), 
    @date date, 
    @_orderBy0 nvarchar (64), 
    @_orderByDirection0 bit'
IF @amount IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Schema].[Entity].[Entity_amount] = @amount))'
IF @otherEntityId IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Schema].[OtherEntity].[OtherEntity_OtherEntityId] = @OtherEntityId))'
IF @date IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Schema].[Entity].[Entity_Date] = @date))'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist,
    @amount, 
    @fromDate, 
    @toDate, 
    @OtherEntityId, 
    @date, 
    @_orderBy0, 
    @_orderByDirection0

RETURN
GO
```

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `SEARCH` method with optional date parameters:

```
SEARCH(date fromDate, date toDate)
WHERE CreationDate >= @fromDate AND CreationDate <= @toDate
```

This generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT @sql=
'SELECT DISTINCT [Employee_Id], [Employee_FirstName], [Employee_CreationDate] 
    FROM [Employee]
    WHERE (1 = 1)'
SELECT @paramlist = '@fromDate datetime, @toDate datetime'
IF @fromDate IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Employee_CreationDate] >= @fromDate))'
IF @toDate IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (([Employee_CreationDate] <= @toDate))'
```

The `fromDate` and `toDate` parameters are not nullable in the generated BOM. However if you use the default value which by default is equal to `CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultDateTimeValue` ([More about default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781816/can-not-save-an-entity-with-the-value-0-for-a-non-nullable-numeric-property)), `NULL` will be sent to the store procedure.

If you prefer `DateTime?` just change the type of the parameter from `date` to `date?`

```
SEARCH(date? fromDate, date? toDate)
WHERE CreationDate >= @fromDate AND CreationDate <= @toDate
```

Which generate the following C# method:

```
public static EmployeeCollection Search(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate)
```

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware about this default parameter value thing. Thanks for this great answer.