# Composite key in entity not reflected in Equals method

Tags: codefluent

Given an Entity "MultipleKeysEntity" with 2 keys keyA and keyB.

KeyA is of type Enumeration; KeyB is of type guid.

Generated code for Equals method thanks to BOM producer doesn't take keyA in consideration. Is it a normal behavior ?

```
<cf:entity name="MultipleKeysEntity" defaultUsePersistenceDefaultValue="false" baseEqualsOverride="false" setType="List" namespace="Project.Namespace" >
    <cf:property name="keyA" persistenceIdentity="false" key="true" typeName="{0}.Enumeration" />
    <cf:property name="keyB" key="true" />
    <cf:property name="property" typeName="decimal" /></cf:entity> 

<cf:enumeration name="Enumeration" namespace="Project.Namespace" >
<cf:enumerationValue name="ONE" />
<cf:enumerationValue name="TWO" /></cf:enumeration>
```

Below the generated code

```
public virtual bool Equals(Project.Namespace.MultipleKeysEntity multipleKeysEntity)
    {
        if ((multipleKeysEntity == null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.keyB == CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultGuidValue))
        {
            return base.Equals(multipleKeysEntity);
        }
        return (this.keyB.Equals(multipleKeysEntity.keyB) == true);
    }
```

Thanks for your answer,

EDIT of 29/08/2016

After setting attribute checkDefaultValue to true, Equals method uses the property as expected. But the first value of the enums is then considered as an "invalid" value.

In particular the method MultipleKeysEntityCollection::baseAdd() prevents me of using value "ONE"

```
protected virtual int BaseAdd(WcfServices.Model.Association.MultipleKeysEntity multipleKeysEntity)
        {
            if ((multipleKeysEntity == null))
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("multipleKeysEntity");
            }
            if (((multipleKeysEntity.keyA == WcfServices.Model.Association.Enumeration.ONE) 
                        || (multipleKeysEntity.keyB.Equals(CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultGuidValue) == true)))
            {
                CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentRuntimeException.Throw("invalidEntityKey", "keyA, keyB", "multipleKeysEntity", "WcfServices.Model.Association.MultipleKeysEntity");
            }
            int localAdd = this.BaseList.Count;
            this.BaseList.Add(multipleKeysEntity);
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.IndexedCollectionChangeEventArgs(System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeAction.Add, multipleKeysEntity, localAdd));
            this.OnListChanged(new System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType.ItemAdded, localAdd));
            return localAdd;
        }
```

The code of the Equals method is given as below:

```
public virtual bool Equals(WcfServices.Model.Association.MultipleKeysEntity multipleKeysEntity)
        {
            if ((multipleKeysEntity == null))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (((this.keyA == WcfServices.Model.Association.Enumeration.ONE) 
                        || (this.keyB == CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultGuidValue)))
            {
                return base.Equals(multipleKeysEntity);
            }
            return ((this.keyA.Equals(multipleKeysEntity.keyA) && this.keyB.Equals(multipleKeysEntity.keyB)) 
                        == true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the enum properties of a composite key are not used for equal comparison. You can instruct the BOM producer to use the property by setting the xml attribute `cfom:checkDefaultValue="true"`:

```
<cf:property name="Id2" cfom:checkDefaultValue="true" />
```

Comment: As added in the EDIT, it prevents me of using value ONE of my enum as a valid value.

Comment: A common practice is to add a default value to the enum (Unknown/Unspecified/None/...). More info about CodeFluent Entities & default values: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35790190/2996339