# Nullable Guid Parameter in RAW method Codefluent Entities

Tags: codefluent

I have a RAW method for an entity that has GUIDS as parameters.

```
LOADONE (Guid CwObjectGuid, Guid CountryGuid) RAW
```

With the corresponding body:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Bid
WHERE Bid_CwObject_Guid = @CwObjectGuid 
AND ((Bid_CountryGuid = @CountryGuid) OR (@CountryGuid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AND Bid_CountryGuid IS NULL))
```

The parameter `CountryGuid` can be a default Guid. However, the method that is generated checks whether the parameter is a default. In that case the method will return `NULL`.

```
        if ((countryGuid.Equals(CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultGuidValue) == true))
        {
            return null;
        }
```

I don't want that check. Can I somehow prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the property is not nullable, so CodeFluent check if the value is equals to the default value (see [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35790190/2996339)). You can disable this behavior by setting `usePersistenceDefaultValue` to `false`:

```
<cf:method name="load" body="LOADONE(...) RAW" rawBody="...">
  <cf:parameter name="countryGuid" usePersistenceDefaultValue="false"/>
</cf:method>
```

You can also send nullable guid to the database

```
<cf:method name="load" body="LOADONE(Guid? id) RAW" rawBody="..." />
```